# Can you make mpld-matplotlib interactive graph web app?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

Can you make mpld3-matplotlib interactive ?

what I mean is display a graph on a web page and be able to update the time series i.e. not simply static graph, but dynamic one page graph-app ?

What can be leveraged from mpld3 ?

Comment: There are many libraries available that can be combined to build it. The question is not if it is possible or not, the question is which libraries one can use.

Comment: i just found also bokeh and dash .. which seem to be for exactly that, should i close the ticket ?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have to support matplotlib then an option is Bokeh or Dash library instead.